# YearFrac in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I need YearFrac (excel function equivalent) in VB.Net.
Currently, I am using below code:

```
(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, StartDate_D, EndDate_D)/ 365) * 12)
```

but there is a slight variance if compared to YearFrac excel function.

Comment: Be aware in excel there is a parameter for the calculation method (basis). Which basis do you want to use? (e.g. 30/360)

Comment: Hi. I am using default basis which is 30/360.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
YearFract = EndDate_D.Year - StartDate_D.Year + (EndDate_D.Month - StartDate_D.Month) / 12 + (EndDate_D.Day - StartDate_D.Day) / 360
```